# ¿Cómo hacer una diferencia con la última fila de una tabla?

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero insertar una fila en una base de datos que tome el valor de la última fila de la base de datos y le reste un número. Tengo problemas para conseguir este número. Para obtener la última fila haciendo esto:

```
SELECT shares FROM shares 
  LIMIT SELECT Count(*) - 1 AS rowcount 
  FROM shares, 1
```

Obtengo:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT Count(*) - 1 AS rowcount FROM shares, 1' at line 2
```

Aqui esta la consulta donde intento insertar:

```
INSERT INTO
`shares` (`Date`, `Shares`)
SELECT CURDATE(), (
                SUM(shares_copylink) + SUM(shares_email) + SUM(shares_facebook) + SUM(shares_messenger) + SUM(shares_pinterest) + SUM(shares_twitter) + SUM(shares_whatsapp) AS total
                FROM communities
                - lo que proviene de la consulta por encima
```

Utiliso SQL 5.7

Parece que [este Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/001e83/21/0) funciona.

Comment: SELECT shares FROM shares 
  LIMIT SELECT Count(*) - 1 AS rowcount 
  FROM shares, 1 tiene tantas cosas mal que no se por donde empezar.. :facepalm: ... que trataste de hacer?

Comment: Obetener la ultima linea de la tabla `shares` @gbianchi ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ entonces diferenciaré la suma de las sumas que puedes ver en el segundo fragmento de SQL con el resultado de esta última línea :)

Comment: Eso no solamente no obtiene la ultima linea, no obtiene nada.. Que es la ultima linea? la ultima linea ordenada como? la unica forma de ordenar un query con sql es usar una clausula order by, que ahi no veo.... No existe concepto de ultima linea en una base de datos....

Comment: En este caso, la línea creada más recientemente @gbianchi

Comment: SEgun que orden? porque no existe un concepto de ultimo registro, salvo que le pongas un timestamp al mismo....

Comment: De acuerdo con el orden cronológico, @gbianchi  he puesto una columna de marca de tiempo en la tabla `shares`.

Comment: OK... todo en la pregunta no??? ahora... tenes un timestamp que es para una fila y todos iguales! o sea.. que queres restar??? No estas siendo claro...

Comment: @gbianchi Sí, este timestamp es visible en el Fiddle pero al principio pensaba utilizar la última fila de la base de datos porque no sabía que no había orden en las BD. Quiero diferenciar entre una suma de sumas de otra tabla y el resultado de la consulta que me da el resultado de la fila más reciente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes obtener la fecha más reciente ordenando de forma desentiende (primero los más recientes y luego los resultados más viejos por `date`).

```
SELECT *
FROM shares
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Usa querys sin `ORDER BY` si realmente no importa el orden, pero si quieres que estén ordenados (obtener el más reciente, el que tenga `X` atributo más grande) es necesario escribir `ORDER BY`.

---

Ver más: [¿Si no uso `ORDER BY`, en que orden se da una consulta?.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20050403/10697526)